# Mapbox keeps crashing

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

My Android application is using the Mapbox SDK. It keeps crashing and it's hard to understand why. Sometimes, it crashes pretty much immediately and sometimes, it works fine for a couple of minutes. I wish I could provide more clues, but the only error I get is:

```
2020-01-17 18:17:31.749 13797-13797/? E/Zygote: v2
2020-01-17 18:21:20.193 13797-28692/com.example.example A/libc: /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r20/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating" failed
2020-01-17 18:21:20.194 13797-28692/com.example.example A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 28692 (Worker 1)
```

The code (almost a copy of one of the examples they provide):

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {

    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationComponent locationComponent;
    private FloatingActionButton FAB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
        // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

        // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the access token is configured.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        FAB = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                centerOnLocation();

            }
        });

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    void centerOnLocation() {

        if (locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation() != null) { // Check to ensure coordinates aren't null, probably a better way of doing this...
            mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() { // necessary or can I refer to mapboxMap directly?
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                    mapboxMap.setCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude(), locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude())).zoom(17).build());
                }
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error with location");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        MainActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;

        mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS,
            new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                    enableLocationComponent(style);
                    centerOnLocation();
                }
            });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({
        "MissingPermission"
    })
    private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

            // Get an instance of the component
            locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();

            // Activate with options
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(
                LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle).build());

            // Enable to make component visible
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

            // Set the component's camera mode
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.NONE);

            // Set the component's render mode
            locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.NORMAL);
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List < String > permissionsToExplain) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_explanation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                    enableLocationComponent(style);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({
        "MissingPermission"
    })
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably filtering your logcat. This will cause you to miss valuable information. Turn off the liftering of logcat and you might see more useful messages about what is the cause of the crash.